# Set cache control from WAMP such that Firefox reports cached pages in the primed cache report

Tags: meta-tags, cache, firefox, cache-control, wamp

So I tried to allow cache by using

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="public, max-age=31536000">
```

but I'm not sure if the content of my pages are actually being cached. Although I receive a 304 code in Firefox Network Monitor, I get 0 cached responses in primed cache. I should be seeing something like this

[image]
<sub>(source: [mozillademos.org](https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/7409/nm-performance.png))</sub>

[This article](https://web.archive.org/web/20220321110450/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor) explains what is see in the network monitor for other sites.

What I am doing wrong? Is this something I must activate in WAMP? Or I must improve something in the tag? I also tried:

```
header("cache-Control:public, max-age=31536000");
header("last-modified: Thu, 04 Sep 2014 03:30:00 GMT");
```

and

```
header("cache-Control:public");
header("last-modified: Thu, 04 Sep 2014 03:30:00 GMT");
```